# Permission to access projects instance with owner gmail on google cloud

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, instance

when I want to run `./gcp.sh instance_up` in google cloud shell says:

> Creating a DNS zone myzone with suffix example.com for the network...
> <
> ERROR: (gcloud.dns.managed-zones.create) User
> [OWNER_GMAIL] does not have permission to access
> projects instance [hyper-123] (or it may not exist): Forbidden

I also added these roles to owner gmail but not work. [image]

Comment: Can you check again the permissions set to your service account in your project?

Comment: @DionV It has owner permission